# nginx serving static files from another server

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

I'm having a nodejs app hosted on a ec2 server. currently i'm having nginx proxying the app and serving the static files from the same machine.

for security reasons i'm implementing another server that will serve as a proxy only, and the main app will sit on another instance and will have only internal from a single ip.

proxying the requests to the internal instance is easy, but i cannot figure out how can i serve static file located on another server...

```
    location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|med$
        root /usr/src/www/static;
        access_log off;
        expires 24h;
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like: ?

```
     location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|med$
        root http://172.10.10.10/static;
        access_log off;
        expires 24h;
    }
```

if so, should i implement another nginx server on the app to serve the files, and simply proxying from the new server?

Answer (score 3):

In the context of nginx, static files would always need to be on a local file system. So you would need to do the proxy_pass to the 'app machine. You may want to just put the app behind nginx as well on the second server, so then your 'proxy' machine is just doing a single proxy_pass and it doesn't need to know or care about what is static and what isn't (unless you have security reasons for needing to separate them at the top-level proxy as well).

This has the added benefit that you can easily add more servers in your app layer and load balance between them with no changes to the proxy level except converting your static proxy_pass into an upstream (or using a "next server").